# Unsetting element in Bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to iterate through a bash array and unset a value if it does not match a regular expression. The code block doesnt change the array, any ideas?

```
    for ((q=0; q<{#array[*]}; q++));
    do
        if [[  ${array[q]} =~ .*\.c$ ]]; then
            :
        else unset array[q]
    done
```

Comment: Please make sure that your code doesn't contain syntax errors by checking it at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that **you keep evaluating `${#array[*]}` in the loop condition instead of determining the array size *once*, *beforehand*.**

In doing so, **you end up missing array elements in your loop**.<sup>[1]</sup>

Try this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=( foo.c non bar.c other ) # sample input

count=${#array[*]} # determine array size *beforehand*
for (( q=0; q < count; q++)); do
  if [[ ${array[q]} =~ \.c$ ]]; then # note: no need for .* before \.c$
      :
  else 
      unset array[q]
  fi
done

printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" # prints 'foo.c' and 'bar.c'
```

<sup>[dancancode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35617226/45375) shows a more concise approach to assigning the array-element count up front: by incorporating it into the *first statement* of the *loop condition*:

`for (( q=0, count=${#array[@]}; q < count; ++q ))`

However, `count` is still implicitly declared in *script* scope (as is `q`), i.e., *not* scoped to the `for` loop.</sup>

Note that while unsetting individual array elements is correctly reflected in the element count `{#array[*]}`, the indices do *not* change, and **you end up with a *sparse* array.**

Thus, when you later enumerate the array, rather than a looping over sequential indices, use:

- either: `for element in "${array[@]}"; ...` - *direct* element enumeration
- or: `for i in ${!array[@]}; do element=${array[i]}; ...` - enumeration via *list* of - potentially non-sequential - *indices* (`${!array[@]}`).

Alternatively, you can **redefine the sparse array based on a copy of itself** to **convert it to a non-sparse array** (sequential indices starting at `0`).

```
array=( "${array[@]}" ) # convert to sequential indices starting at 0
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> A demonstration of the problem:

```
array=( one two three four )
for (( i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)); do
  echo "element: ${array[i]}; element count: ${#array[@]}"
  unset array[i]
done
```

yields

```
element: one; element count: 4
element: two; element count: 3
```

In other words: *only the first 2 out of 4* elements were processed, because the diminishing array count (`${#array[@]}`) in every iteration (due to unsetting elements) leads to premature termination of the loop.

Note the implication: `${#array[@]}` always reflects the element *count*, whether the array is sparse (has non-sequential indices) or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing `fi` for the `if` statement. However, pattern matching is a little simpler here, and lets you use the `!=` operator to avoid the need for the `else` clause.

```
for ((q=0; q<${#array[*]}; q++));
do
    if [[  ${array[q]} != *.c ]]; then
        unset array[q]
    fi
done
```

Comment: While it's true that pattern matching is slightly simpler in this case, negation can also be had with regex matching: `[[ ! ${array[q]} =~ \.c$ ]]`

Comment: I was going to suggest that initially, but then decided to combine negation and pattern matching into one change.

Comment: Got it. The problem with the OP's - and also your - loop is that by basing the loop condition on the _current-in-each-iteration_ array count, not all array elements are processed if at least 1 element is unset.

Comment: You know, if this had been a Python question, I would have noticed that immediately. Too tired to fix it tonight, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=('1' '2' '3' '4' 'abcd' '5')
$echo "${array[@]}"
1 2 3 4 abcd 5
$cnt=${#array[@]}
$for ((q=0;q<cnt;q++))
do
    if [[ ${array[q]} =~ ^[0-9]$ ]]
    then
        :
    else
        unset array[q]
    fi
done
$ echo "${array[@]}"
1 2 3 4 5
```

Another shorthand which you can use is like this

```
cnt=${#array[@]}
for ((q=0;q<cnt;q++))
do
    [[ ${array[q]} =~ ^[0-9]$ ]] || unset array[q]
done
```

You are also missing `fi` in `if`, a syntax error

```
cnt=${#array[@]}
for ((q=0; q<cnt; q++));
do
    if [[  ${array[q]} =~ .*\.c$ ]]; then
        :
    else 
         unset array[q]
    fi
done
```

Shorthand

```
cnt=${#array[@]}
for ((q=0; q<cnt; q++));
do
    [[  ${array[q]} =~ .*\.c$ ]] || unset array[q]
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a portion of a larger script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

prune () { eval "for ((i=0, j=\${#$1[@]}; i<j; i++)); do [[ \${$1[i]} == $2 ]] && unset '$1[i]'; done; $1=(\"\${$1[@]}\")"; }

rpms=(*.rpm)
[[ $rpms ]] || exit 0

prune rpms '@(MQSeries|grafana|influxdb)*'
```

`unset` actually works, but it leaves holes in the array.  If you redefine the array to include itself, the holes will go away.